# Sql databases select command

Tags: sql, database, select, inner-join

I am new to databases. And our teacher gave us pretty hard assignment. There are two tables. First table nickname is abilities(of superhero's:) ) and second table name superheros.

We have to select nick of Superhero and his average(medial) range for those who has two abilities?

Image of both tables:

[image: http://postimg.org/image/85pqbc47n/]

Original here: http://postimg.org/image/85pqbc47n/

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because does not show any attempt by the poster to answer the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `HAVING` and `AVG()` for this:

```
SELECT s.NickName, AVG(a.Range)
FROM abilities a
JOIN superhero s
 ON a.ID_SuperHero = s.ID_SuperHero
GROUP BY s.NickName
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT a.Abilities > 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

I will not give you solution - after all, it's homework and you have to learn something :) But I can give you an advice - try to do one task at a time

- first, find those superheroes who has only 2 abilities (actually, you can do this by quering only table with abilities)
- second - try to find average range of abilities for all superheroes (here you'll need join)
- combine your queries

take a look at [join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29), [group by](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp), [count](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_count.asp) and [having](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Having_%28SQL%29)

Don't feel bad if you can't write it at first attempt, your query is not super easy, but 'm sure you can do this.

Comment: Thanks for good advice. I am trying those things. Don't go away)

Comment: @ReuvenVolnoboy I'm here for about half an hour, feel free to ask